# What does it mean if my (zsh) shell throws these errors/warnings at me every time I open the terminal?

Tags: macos, shell, unix, zsh

This is what I see every time I launch my Terminal.app since I upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/zsh
  Reason: image not found
zsh: trace trap
/Users/user/sandbox/repos/zsh-notify/notify.plugin.zsh:55: command not found: add-zsh-hook
/Users/user/sandbox/repos/zsh-notify/notify.plugin.zsh:56: command not found: add-zsh-hook
```

To see if permissions might be messed up, I checked

```
➜  exp-scotty  where zsh
/usr/local/bin/zsh
/usr/local/bin/zsh
/bin/zsh
/bin/zsh
➜  exp-scotty  ll `where zsh`
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel   538K Sep 10 01:19 /bin/zsh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel   538K Sep 10 01:19 /bin/zsh
lrwxr-xr-x  1 milan  admin    27B Oct 28 10:59 /usr/local/bin/zsh -> ../Cellar/zsh/5.0.7/bin/zsh
lrwxr-xr-x  1 milan  admin    27B Oct 28 10:59 /usr/local/bin/zsh -> ../Cellar/zsh/5.0.7/bin/zsh
```

Versions:

```
➜  exp-scotty  sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.10.1
BuildVersion:   14B25

➜  exp-scotty  /bin/zsh --version
zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)

➜  exp-scotty  /usr/local/bin/zsh --version
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/zsh
  Reason: image not found
[1]    81495 trace trap  /usr/local/bin/zsh --version
```

**What might be going wrong? And/or how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means you are trying to use `add-zsh-hook` without loading it. Your shell config is missing `autoload -U add-zsh-hook`. Other than that you're missing `libpcre` assuming you're using `brew` you'll likely need to reinstall and relink it.

Comment: I've put `autoload -U add-zsh-hook` into my `.zshrc`, and followed the instructions given by `brew doctor` and now all the errors are gone. Thanks for the pointers!